# Listing all logged in user and saving it into a text file in C, linux

Tags: c, linux

i would like to know how can i list all the current logged user and save it to a text file and list all files info on the current directory and save it as well using c. i have tried system("w"), system("ls -l") to list the users but it wont save using fprintf and the only output i get is 0 and nothing for ls -l. i'm relatively new into programming and linux. please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
        char opt;
        printf("Enter an Option A/B: ");
        scanf("%c", &opt);
        if (opt == 'A')
        {
                int list;
                time_t tm;
                time(&tm);
                int i,j;
                i = system("w");
                j = system("ls -l");
                printf("The Date and Time are: %s", ctime (&tm));
                printf("\n");
                FILE *fptr;
                fptr = fopen("file1.txt", "w");
                fprintf(fptr, "%s", ctime (&tm));
                fprintf(fptr, "%i", i);
                fprintf(fptr, "%j", j);
                fclose(fptr);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("bye");
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `last` is just made for that ([man last](https://linux.die.net/man/1/last)).

Comment: I guess you're confusing formatting options and variables. There is `%i` formatter for integer and  `%j` formatter for max integers in current libc `printf`. Diplaying decimal value then.

Comment: (`%ij%`for max integers) The `0` you get then means that the `system` calls were successful, but it is not the `output` of theses system calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with popen(), fgets read the file line at a time. You can replace printf function with anything you like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
...


FILE *fp;
int status;
char path[PATH_MAX];


fp = popen("ls *", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;


while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    printf("%s", path);


status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
    ...
} else {
    /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
       to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
    ...
}
```

code source: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html